# Display XIB before UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I'm facing this problem for a couple of months and i don't know what is the best solution to solve it.The problem is,i need to load a XIB before my UITabBar shows up,more clearly,i have my first view which is to the user login(NO TABBAR SHOULD BE DISPLAYED),when user login,the app verify the information and after should load the view with a UITabBarController,but every time i try do that without presenting the login view modally,both of the views are displayed,the login view and the tabbar view.

Comment: So you don't want to display a modal view to ask for credentials? Is that right?

Comment: Yes,i need to show the login view but no modally!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set first the loginViewController as `rootViewController` of your main `window`, then after the user is logged in, set the tabBarController as `rootViewController`.

Something like this (assume your loginViewController is `viewController1`):

```
Appdelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myNav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UINavigationController *myNav2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNav1,myNav2, nil];
    //set the login view
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController1;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)setTabBar{
    //self.viewController1=nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

Then from the loginViewController call the method `setTabBar` of the appDelegate.

```
LoginViewController.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)loginOK{
   AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [del setTabBar];
   //you could add some animation transition between views
}
```

Comment: ps: uinavigationcontrollers are optional.

Comment: and what if user gets logged out ?

Comment: @Maulik Create another similar method like `setTabBar` and set the loginViewController again as rootviewcontroller. Then use NSUserDefault at the launch of the app to check if the user is already logged in. Not so difficult.

Comment: I know that is not easy to reproduce the same effect as the pop of the  navcontroller, but imho I think there should not be an animation for the logout, at most a fade animation. This is just my point of view, but you can always access to the view of the rootvc and to the view of the next vc you're showing, so you can recreate a similar pop effect.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `UITabBarController` can not to be embedded in another `viewController`. With that in mind, you have these choices:

1. Present a modal view (that you don't want)
2. Hide `tabBar` on launch, and once credentials are verified, show the `tabBar`. But there is a downside: hiding/showing `tabBar` can not be animated.
3. You can initiate your `UITabBarController` with only one `viewController` - the one that is going to ask for credentials, and once verified, add more `viewControllers` to the `UITabBarController` (that will add more tabs). This is also the kind of behavior you can see in some app, e.g. [Bank of America](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bank-america-mobile-banking/id284847138?mt=8) (http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bank-america-mobile-banking/id284847138?mt=8)

There might be better practices. These are my suggestions.

Comment: Yes,i've already tried this,but keep in mind that doing this,one of the UITabBar items must be my login view,which should be remove from view after the login!

Comment: Right. That's what the app I mentioned as an example does. When you launch it, it has the login tab, once you are logged in, that viewController is removed from UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

As an easy way, add your view as a subview of your window, and dismiss it when you don't need it anymore.

For example, put this code in your appdelegate (assuming `loginController` is a property of your appdelegate...there are other ways, this is just an example):

```
[self.window addSubview:self.loginController.view];
```

When you want to dismiss the view, remove it:

```
[self.loginController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Don't forget to properly release `loginController`.

This way your view is just simply "overlayed" over your tabbar views. There are other answers here that effectively only swap the tabbar view into your view hierarchy after your login is complete, if that's what you want.

Comment: Isn't addSubView is not recommended for standalone UIViewControllers and it supposed to be for views?