# Creating UITabBarController in Nib instead of Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am trying to create a **UITabBarController** **from a** **Nib**.

In my project, I **do not use Storyboards** at all, I prefer going the Nib method, as it makes the project much more managable.

So here is what I did so far

I create a new CocoaTouch class file and I check the **Also Create XIB File**

[image: Screenshot 1]

Then I got two files

[image: Screenshot 2]

But in the xib file, I didnt get the usual UITabBarController as how we usually get from a Storyboard UITabBarController. I only got a **View**..

[image: Screenshot 3]

I am wondering what is the proper way to create a UITabBarController usig NIB/Xib?

Thank yu!!

Comment: Check this : http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762975/display-xib-before-uitabbarcontroller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to delete that XIB and drag a Tab Bar Controller  to the canvas . set you class to that file . or either you can see this video tutorial that will help you to understand how you can use XIB/Nib file for Tab bar controller and to add ViewController to the tab bar controller and set title for each tab .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfEK9JsCyXM

Comment: This means that we do not create TabBarController in Nib right? Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/30545143/trying-to-use-flourishui-ios-control